# Why does FileZilla still open .txt files in Scratch?

Tags: files, ssh, default

I've set FileZilla to automatically download and open files when I double click them. Here are my settings for "File editing" on FileZilla:

[image: File editing settings on FileZilla]

Gedit is my default text editor in System Preferences, and I've even searched `usr/share/applications/defaults.list` for references to Scratch and have found none. (Text files are set to be opened in Gedit.) I've tried `sudo apt remove scratch`, but it appears not to be installed. Even still, when I double-click a `.txt` file, it opens in Scratch. How can I fix this?

Text files open in Gedit when I select "Always use default editor", but I want to avoid this because then other file types (`.wav`, `.mp4`, etc) open in Gedit as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution that works for now is to set a custom filetype association within FileZilla:

[image: Filetype associations menu]

Answer (score 0):

This works for me `/usr/bin/scratch-text-editor`. Good luck

[image]

Comment: No, I want to change it so it never uses Scratch. Right now it uses Scratch when I don't want it to.

Comment: Oh! I see... Sorry